# DataGridView - changing color of columns

Tags: c#, .net

I have a datagridview in this format:

```
Days | one | two | three | four | five
day1 |cell |cell |...ect
day2
day3
day4
day5
```

What I'm trying to do is change the backround color of the day1,day2..ect cells. 
while I'm here, is it possible to make those said cells read-only so any input starts at row "one" cell 1 and so on, so I don't overwrite days.

Comment: you want to change the color of entire Days column and make it uneditable

Comment: @COLDTOLD yeps, I've sorted out the coloring, now i just need to make it uneditable

Answer (score 0):

if you are using winforms it should be something like this

```
dataGridView1.Columns["Days "].ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify how you handled the color so I thought i'd provide some feedback that may help.

When changing columns it's best to set the `dataGridViewColumn.DefaultCellStyle` instead of iterating through the cells in the column and setting the style of each one.